# say "Is setOnInsert functions helps to insert a new field to existing document?"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have tried to insert a new field to existing document in my collection.I have used "**setOnInsert"** method and **"upsert:"true"**.Even though it's not working.Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks in advance...

```html
 async function doupdate(name){

  const result=await CoursesList.findOneAndUpdate({name:name},{
    $setOnInsert: { NoofBooks: 100 }`enter code here`
  },{upsert:true,new:true});
  
  console.log(result);
}

doupdate("Express.js Course");
```